# How to setup proper typescript linting for an angular project in vscode?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tslint, airbnb-js-styleguide

I would like to setup an angular project which uses the airbnb typescript styleguide and also formats the code on save in vscode. I've tried to configure it with `tslint-config-airbnb` and also the prettier extension. But somehow I can't manage it.

Answer (score 2):

Install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin) plugin if not already there.

VC Code should be linting your project dynamically as you code and show errors just in time they appear.

You may need to run linting manually (or on a testing environment). In this case, you must be able to find "lint" script in your package.json which you execute as `npm run lint`.

Comment: TS Lint has been great but it's now deprecated in favor of [this resource](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint#typescript-eslint). A bit too much commotion in my opinion.   :)